# Alignment issue in GridView when contents have no space in between

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net, gridview

This is a scenario

SLNo      FirstName     LastName    Description

1    AA           BB   descriptiondfgfdfgdfgdfgfdgdfgdfgfdgfdgf

```
                     gfggfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfg
```

2    CC           BB    descriptionfdfdfdfdfdf

Entire row just moves to right.. How can we fix the issue..
There is no issue even there is a space between,
How to handle this issue.

This issue was posted already in http://forums.asp.net/t/1228361.aspx/1 by someone else.
As a solution, we need to wrap it by adding this code
e.Row.Cells[4].Attributes.Add("style", "WORD-BREAK:BREAK-ALL");

If so , this has to be written in which event ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Michael : Thanks for formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word-Break doesn't work in all browser. However, you can do the following to restrict the text limit.

```
private void OnItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {   
        if(e.Item.Cells[3].Text > 50)
           e.Item.Cells[3].Text= e.Item.Cells[3].Text.SubString(0, 47) + "...";
           // Or add space after 50 characters.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks..But I dont have any such label ("dgLabel1") ..Data is just bound to gridview ..

Answer (score 3):

use the `OnPreRenderComplete` event, this one acts after the other ones (`OnLoad`, `OnInit`...)

```
public void OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e) {
     if(!Page.IsPostBack) {
         ....
     }
}
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.onprerendercomplete.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Issue fixed by  adding Word-Break in RowDataBound event

protected void HcidGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            // Cell[5] indicates Comment column
            e.Row.Cells[5].Attributes.Add("style", "WORD-BREAK:BREAK-ALL");
        }